# How to add image ontop of step progress bar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to add an image/icon ontop of the progress bar for each step. I already tried inserting an image tag but this places the image just beside the 'step 1' which is something i do not want.

```css
.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}
.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content:none;
}
.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #3aac5d;
  background: #3aac5d;
  color: white
}
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
}

.container {
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 0px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active"> step 1</li>
    <li>step 2</li>
    <li>step 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

It should be just above each of the circles. For example a location icon/image on step 1, shopping cart on step etc.

**EDIT**
I would like to achieve something like this in my example. This is a tutorial from [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eU-7UmXZPGY).

[image]

Comment: In youtube video , it is clearly shown how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```css
.progressbar {
  counter-reset: step;
}
.progressbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before {
  content: counter(step);
  counter-increment: step;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.progressbar li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  top: 15px;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after {
  content:none;
}
.progressbar li.active {
  color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before {
  border-color: #3aac5d;
  background: #3aac5d;
  color: white;
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://i.picsum.photos/id/1036/4608/3072.jpg?hmac=Tn9CS_V7lFSMMgAI5k1M38Mdj-YEJR9dPJCyeXNpnZc');
background-size: 30px 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.progressbar li.active + li:after {
  background-color: green;
}

.container {
  padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 0px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active"> step 1</li>
    <li>step 2</li>
    <li>step 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really. I edited my question to reflect the expected results. I will like the icon to be above like in the image i posted

Answer (score 0):

Looking the Youtube link as you mentioned.

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="progressbar">
    <li class="active">
      <img src="IMAGE_PATH">
      <p>Step 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="IMAGE_PATH">
      <p>Step 2</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="IMAGE_PATH">
      <p>Step 3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this before and it places the icon below. I want to put it above the circles.

Comment: He used <i> tag instead of counter-increment: step; that you using in counter-increment: step;